# Last_Value returning the current value

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am not able to get the last value, rather it is just returning the same value with my code below in snowflake - does anyone have any idea? Is there something glaring wrong?

```
select MNTH, 
       sum_cust, 
       last_value(sum_cust) over (partition by MNTH order by sum_cust desc ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) as sum_cust_last
from block_2;
```

Comment: Last by what measure?

Comment: by MONTH, as I just want a column that shows what the sum_cust was for the last month @Nick

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I did, it is under peer review - a very poor rendition is below a comment to Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you actually want is to `LAG` the value from the previous `MNTH`:

```
SELECT MNTH, 
       sum_cust, 
       LAG(sum_cust) OVER (ORDER BY MNTH) AS sum_cust_last
FROM block_2;
```

Comment: Thank you getting closer, but that is just showing 1 value for all the sum_cust_last @Nick.

Comment: @0004 do you have a field which identifies the customer?

Comment: @0004 I guess I'm confused. If you could show some sample data in your question that would help. On what basis do you expect there to be different values?

Comment: each row is unique, it is only two columns , so 1 sum_cust per 1 MNTH @NICK

Comment: Well then `LAST_VALUE` can only give one result, the result for the last value of `MNTH`. What are you expecting?

Comment: sorry waiting for edits from peer review , but I want sum_cust_last to be each value from the last month:CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_1` 


INSERT INTO `table_1` (`date`, `cust`) 
VALUES ('1-1-20', '386'),
       ('2-1-20', '399'),
       ('3-1-20', '444')
       ;
      
      

  INSERT INTO `desired_table` (`date`, `cust`, `desire`) 
VALUES ('1-1-20', '386', 'Null'),
       ('2-1-20', '399', '386'),
       ('3-1-20', '444', '399')
       ;

Comment: @0004 I think what you actually want is `LAG`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

I actually recommend `first_value()` rather than `last_value()` for some technical reasons involving window frames.  If you want the last value, order by the month desc and choose the first row:

```
select MNTH, sum_cust,
       first_value(sum_cust) over (order by MNTH desc
                                   rows between current_row AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
                                  ) as sum_cust_last
from block_2;
```